# how to upload my local repository to archiva

Tags: maven, archiva

I am setting up an apache archiva instance to server as our development team's local repository.  I'd like to initially seed it with the artifacts in my local .m2 repository.  However, as far as I can tell, the [depoly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) plugin and the [repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-repository-plugin/usage.html) plugin work only with individual projects.  I have also configured my local settings.xml file to deploy artifacts to archiva when built with maven, as shown in the [archiva documentatation](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/userguide/deploy.html).  Also, I'm aware that it's possible to upload artifacts via archiva's [webUI form](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M4/userguide/deploy.html).  This would still require me to upload jars individually.  Is there a way to automate this or do some sort of mass upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deploy plugin can do it for you. (use deploy-file goal)
See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/file-deployment.html